# How to Develop iOS or Mac apps?

Tags: macos, ios, xcode, development, app-store-connect

I know Apple needs developers to be a part of the iOS Developer Program or Mac Developer Program to acquire several solutions and am interested in knowing how to start.

What tools are needed for making my first app with Xcode and how would I start to become a developer using Apple's tools?

Comment: On the one hand you are looking for guidance, on the other you are connected to a site which claims iOS development expertise. Can you elaborate on what your actual question is?

Comment: Hii, i have recently joined a company in which i need to make apps for iOS devices and i want to know the scope of this field and guidelines for making apps using Xcode and what is the use of Xcode in this?

Comment: Ask Different focuses on end-user problems. For developer issues, stackexchange.com might be the better place (or developer.apple.com of course).

Comment: Does anyone object to me editing this to steer this to some very high level resources - a summary of what is needed could be objectively answered and perhaps get some good subjective answers. I agree we don't want to have a "shopping for Mac that runs Xcode best" or "list of book recommendation" -type question, though.

Comment: The question is more oriented towards development and there exists a possible Duplicate:- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9309052/ios-application-development-beginner

Comment: That duplicate was closed in Feb 12 for being non constructive - which it is on SO - Now I would vote to close as too broad on SO.

Comment: @bmike this is too broad. To start developing apps you need the equivalent of several books and depends on what your current skills are which books - so I would say this is too broad

Comment: A broad question could have a broad answer that still helps people out to know where to start. Just like other questions, we may need to correct course, edit, clarify and moderate poor answers with votes, edits and comments.

Comment: @ChrisW.Rea If so, we'll see how well that works out for them and for the site ;-)

Answer (score 1):

The requirements to become a developer are quite low although the skills and attitude to do so effectively take time and training to perfect.

To get started using exclusively Apple's tools and free guidance, the initial investment needed in hardware and accounts is:

1. [Any Mac](http://store.apple.com/us/browse/home/specialdeals) (used is fine) that runs [Mountain Lion](http://www.apple.com/osx/)
2. An [Apple ID](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT2534) to download [Xcode](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/xcode/id497799835?mt=12) with the current iOS / Mac SDK

You should perhaps budget a week of partial effort (several hours a night or half a day each weekend day) to start working through the introductory articles on http://developer.apple.com for either Mac or iOS. If you are not familiar with programming in C and some sort of graphical framework, your progress will be very slow as there will be an overwhelming amount of information (like trying to take a sip of water from a fire hydrant - rather than a water fountain).

After a few hours of experimenting, you can have an informed opinion of how your development will progress and whether you'll want to take a guided course, spend time learning Cocoa or Objective-C or if you instead could use tools like [RubyMotion](http://www.rubymotion.com) to avoid needing to learn C, Objective-C or Cocoa.

You will at some point need a paid Mac Developer account to get access to prerelease software, Apple code level support, code signing credentials and access to the Mac App Store. Similarly, your iOS development will at some point need a paid developer membership for similar support and tools. These programs each cost $99 for a year of program benefits.

Comment: Things like RubyMotion in theory don't require the need to learn Cocoa however I suspect in practice you will need to to look at Cocoa documentation for some requirements. Looking at the details I suspect you need to learn all of Cocoa as MacRuby is ject a way to replace Objective C

Comment: I try to give a lot of rep back in bounties, but I'm more interested in getting people's eyes on the best answers as opposed to racking up another 3k in any one week or month. Would you be up for asking the canonical and pinging me in comments?

Answer (score 1):

The other thing you will need to become an apple developer apart from the ones listed above is an iPhone.

The simulators that come with Xcode are good for testing your code runs, however to really make sure your app is behaving how you want it you will need several models of iPhone on hand to test.

Comment: Which model of iphone i need to use? Kindly also explain what factors should i consider while testing.

Comment: Ideally you would have every model of iPhone on hand that is available.  The factors depend on what you are developing, I would consider usability, stability, functionality etc...